# Destroy Angular2 Application

Tags: performance, angular, memory-management

I have a requirement to destroy Angular2 Application when user is navigated to other page (Note: It is an application where we are using angular2 for one page only). So when the user navigates away from this page, we have to unbootstrap the ng2 app.

I am taking applicationRef as follows:

```
platformBrowserDynamic([
    {provide: 'ConfigService', useValue: {} }
]).bootstrapModule(AppModule).then((appModule:NgModuleRef<AppModule>)=>{
    const appRef = appModule.injector.get(ApplicationRef);

    if(!!callback)
        callback(appRef);
});
```

And when this page destroys, I am calling

```
_ref.components[0].hostView.destroy();
```

where **_ref** is the application reference passed in the callback above.

This entire flow calls the **ngOnDestroy** of each component inside the application however, when I navigate to non angular page, I can see that the components are still there in the memory and causing performance issue when I open the same page again.

[image: Chrome Profile tab of chrome]

You can see from the screenshot that the component are still present and consuming memory, even if I have destroyed the app as mentioned above.

What is the issue here. Is destroying application not enough to clear the memory?

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a very old question but this could be helpful.

If you are looking for an event that executes when the angular app is destroyed, you can use the `PlatformRef` which has an `OnDestroy()` callback

in main.ts

```js
function doSomethingOnAppDestory() {
  console.log('test');
}

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule).then(ref => {

  // Ensure Angular destroys itself on hot reloads.
  if (window['ngRef']) {
    window['ngRef'].destroy();
  }
  window['ngRef'] = ref;

  ref.onDestroy(doSomethingOnAppDestory);

  // Otherwise, log the boot error
}).catch(err => console.error(err));
```

See the [stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-n2qngc?file=src%2Fmain.ts)